# Syncing Avatars across multisite

Tags: customization, multisite, uploads, avatar

There's gotta be a way. I have tried a bunch of different multisite sync plugins and they sync users and roles just fine (even paid for plugins to do so)....but avatars don't sync.

My registration form handles the image upload just fine -- and assigns it to the user (but only on the one site the registration came from) -- and shows blank/no image/avatar on the rest.

I've nearly been pulling my hair out on this and while I don't have a lot of money, if this was a need to pay a little for some help, I'd be willing....

I really want to sync avatars across sites in a multisite - even if it's moving the upload directory for avatars in some way....or even if it links to where they were originally uploaded (the site it uploaded on) - or..... copies them to each site....I don't care how it does it, as long as it does it....

Thank you so much.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used the following plugins: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-user-sync/ (Actually got the pro version)
and 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-user-sync/
and of course scoured the web for ideas and code but found nothing that worked.. I can't even go over all the thing I have scoured

Comment: There were some weird snippets on the web that I think were designed around buddypress or another system as well but some were 6-8 years old and I'd rather not add buddypress on top of everything else I'm running in this network, that sounds like a large addition when my registrations and everything else is handled well as it is

Comment: How do you want to perform the sync? Main site to sub sites **or** Sub site to main site?

Comment: Ideally both ways. There are two sites (at the moment and I hope to keep it that way) that have registrations. The reason there's two different registrations, is one (on the main site) is for normal everyday users to chatroom and such with the site - whereas the other registration automatically gives musicians an Artists account (custom role which yes has been synced on all sites) which gives them the ability to create Artists/Bands profiles...something a regular account wouldn't do.

Comment: I know there's not going to be a free answer to this with a complex situation..but like those plugins, and the one I got the pro of, users go both ways...added or deleted from a site, removed from the rest. option of role sync between sites with it too...but sadly, why not profile/avatar pictures? I'm kinda disappointed that it didn't do that when I thought it would...guess I was wrong to think. I just need help making this happen as it's driving me a little crazy.

Comment: So do you have a main site? You could hook to some filters to redirect all the requests of avatars to the main site.

Comment: Also, how are you handling the custom avatar part? By default WP uses Gravatar which is already 'centralized' so I imagine you're using a custom solution which is why these plugins might not work with your avatars.

Comment: Yes, there's a main site. The two sites that would have avatars as they are two separate registration forms (and have to stay that way) -- are the primary site and the artists site. If I could find a way to get those two at parity with eachother and then always pull from one once the two were at parity.

Comment: So, should I be disabling gravatar? I did try a couple different plugins for avatars. My registration forms are with Formidable (and they offer no advice in this custom situation) and when I set the "create user option" the photo to the photo upload field, it does so - at least on the site the user registered from. I did also try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/ which seems to mimick whatever is in my upload but can also be called I believe I read (not 100% on this) with the meta key of simple_local_avatar....

Comment: Can you add info on how you deal with the custom avatar on the registration form?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I have a file upload field, one single image...and in the options for the form, I have avatar pointing to the thing. As in this section here: https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/user-registration/#kb-create-registration-form

Comment: Let's continue over chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108353/ca-legendre-help

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq." Guess I can't chat? - I'm open to being contacted on Telegram or something like that - username is @legendre - or if you have another suggestion... unless there's a quick reputation fix. I am sure I had an old account on here tied to an old email but I had to make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin "Simple local Avatar" is going to do what you need, once this new PR lands: https://github.com/10up/simple-local-avatars/issues/26#issuecomment-814157532